# makefile compiles object file with no rule

Tags: c, makefile

My makefile is compiling write_time.o although i'm not giving it any rule. However, when I actually write a rule for it, it wouldn't compile. Any suggestion on what might cause this problem? Below is my makefile:

```
INCLUDES = -I../include -I/opt/local/include
CC = gcc

OBJS = image_io.o xcorr.o textfile_io.o main.o array_processing.o \
       fit2d.o poly.o mattran.o matsolve.o nelder_mead.o process.o \
       open_seq_file.o write_time.o close_seq_file.o

DEBUGS = -g
CFLAGS = $(INCLUDES) -Wall -O2 $(DEBUGS)
DESTDIR = ../bin
LDFLAGS = -L. -L/opt/local/lib -ltiff -lm -L../lib -lmatrix ../include/seq_io.h
DEPS = ../include/file_io.h ../include/corr.h \
       ../include/matrix.h /opt/local/include/tiffio.h \
       /opt/local/include/tiff.h ../include/seq_io.h
       #../include/nmsimplex.h 

all: $(DESTDIR)/main

image_io.o: image_io.c ../include/file_io.h /opt/local/include/tiffio.h \
               /opt/local/include/tiff.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

xcorr.o: xcorr.c ../include/file_io.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c  $<

textfile_io.o: textfile_io.c ../include/file_io.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

array_processing.o: array_processing.c ../include/file_io.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

fit2d.o: fit2d.c ../include/matrix.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

poly.o: poly.c ../include/corr.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

nelder_mead.o: nelder_mead.c ../include/corr.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
# nmsimplex.o: nmsimplex.c ../include/nmsimplex.h
    # $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
process.o: process.c ../include/corr.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

mattran.o: mattran.c ../include/matrix.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

matsolve.o: matsolve.c ../include/matrix.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

open_seq_file.o: open_seq_file.c ../include/seq_io.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

close_seq_file.o: close_seq_file.c ../include/seq_io.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

main.o: main.c ../include/file_io.h ../include/nmsimplex.h ../include/corr.h ../include/seq_io.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -fopenmp -c $<

$(DESTDIR)/main: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ -fopenmp $^ $(LDFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~
```

This compiles fine. But when I add in:

```
write_time.o: write_time.c ../include/seq_io.h
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

I get the error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `../include/seq_io.h', needed by `write_time.o'. Stop.
```

Comment: You're missing an indentation for the rule. Also, `make` provides default rules for many types of files (including C files) - that's why it compiles without the rule.

Comment: ok. that did it, but why would it compile when i don't put in the rule though?

Comment: Like I said, `make` will try several default rules if it doesn't find any explicitly stated in a makefile. In this case, it sees that you're asking for `write_time.o`, and it sees that `write_time.c` exists, so it invokes `cc write_time.c -o write_time.o`.

Comment: didn't know 'make' is that smart

Answer (score 1):

That error probably means that `../include/seq_io.h` doesn't exist. You've listed it as a dependency, and `make` insists that dependencies either exist or that there is some way to automatically create them.

Comment: He has used `../include/seq_io.h` in other rules, for example, in `open_seq_file.o`.  I'll hazard a guess that the `.o` files for those rules already exist by compiling in a different directory.  Can the OP do a `make clean` and then, a `make` to see what happens in the current directory?

Comment: @unxnut: ask the OP, not me :). I agree, the existence of the dependencies in other rules suggests that the other rules haven't been tested.

Comment: Drew McGowen just solved the problem. I somehow managed forget indentation. And when I remove the rule completely, 'make' takes a guess at how i want to compile write_time.o.

Comment: @theninety'er: cool, glad you got it sorted out. The default rules for make are actually well documented, and cover a wide variety of simple single file builds. See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules